# Cannot set property 'tgt' of null

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Recently began recieving this error in logs from many users on my website:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'tgt' of null
at HTMLDocument.r (eval at C (eval at exec_fn (unknown source)), :43562:25)
```

It happens only in Chrome (from v45 to the latest) and seems to come from some browser add-on/extension and persists on other websites too (as my Googling showed). But there's no way to tell the source.

Has anyone encountered this error? Or is there any method of investigation?

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://github.com/kogg/InstantLogoSearch/issues/199) say it's [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)

Comment: Not exactly. It says: "I got this error in "savefrom.net" script for tampermonkey.". Tried installing both but still didn't get the error.